# D3 chart visible in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js

I created a D3.js chart and it renders properly in Firefox but it shows a `cross-origin error` with an `uncaught progress event` error in Chrome.

The script and csv are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>

    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #F2F2F2;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

  .d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

<script>

function filter_Data(d) {
  if (d.getDate(d.date) % 2 ==0)
   {
    return true;
  }
}

var margin = {top: 120, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 140},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%d %b, %Y");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .5);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%a, %b %d"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(3);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Date:</strong> <span style='color:Black'>" + formatTime(d.date) + "</span>" + "</br><strong>Amount Spent:</strong> $<span style='color:Black'>" + d.value;
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {


    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  var data2 = data.filter(function(d) {
    return filter_Data(d.date)
  });


  x.domain(data2.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data2, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-60)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -55)
      .attr("x", -90)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .text("Amount Spent ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data2)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "#6760C3")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)


});

</script>

</body>
```

CSV:

```
date,value
1/1/2018,53
1/2/2018,165
1/3/2018,269
1/4/2018,344
1/5/2018,376
1/6/2018,410
1/7/2018,421
1/8/2018,405
1/9/2018,376
1/10/2018,359
1/11/2018,392
1/12/2018,433
1/13/2018,455
1/14/2018,478
```

The `.csv` file and the `.html` file are in the same folder and it renders properly on firefox as shown in the image below.[image: firefox rendering]
Can someone help me understand why chrome wont render it?

Comment: Did you try it from a server? or local file system?

Comment: Both the files are on my machine so its a local file system.

Comment: Try to run it on a local server like xampp

Comment: Is there no way to figure out why it won't work without a local server?